# Vue/Laravel: Using query params to avoid caching

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I am having an issue with my bundled Vue js being cached so I'm going to start versioning.  However, I'm confused as to which is the correct way of doing this.  I know I should reference the JS file in the Blade file by adding a query string to make the server think it's a new file but do I have to do anything to the actual app.js file then?

`<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ cdn('/js/app.js') }}"></script>`

EDIT:

Laravel Mix's built in versioning using `mix()` not working because I am accessing the JS file through a custom CDN helper:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js?v=123"></script>`

```
function cdn($file)
{
    return env('CDN_URI', '').'/'.ltrim($file, '/');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Laravel with Vue.js, I'm guessing you're using [Laravel Mix](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix), and if not you probably should. And Laravel Mix already offers [cache busting](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting) via query string hashes. So if you were to use Laravel Mix is would be as simple as having this in your `webpack.mix.js` file:

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').version();
```

And then using the `mix` helper function in you Blade file:

```
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

This will output to something like this:

```
<script src="/js/app.js?id=a7af6e15c9595bb9d346"></script>
```

with the hash automatically changing whenever there is a change to your JS files.

---

So yes, your approach of adding a query string value that changes with the version is good. But unless you have a strong reason against it, I suggest using **Laravel Mix**, as versioning is just one of the many benefits you get from it.

---

**EDIT**

To work around your particular issue you can modify your helper function to look like this:

```
function cdn($file, $useMix = false)
{
    return env('CDN_URI') . ($useMix ? mix($file) : $file);
}
```

This will work exactly the same only it will prepend your custom CDN to the relative path outputed by the mix helper. And if you want to use for both cases:

```
// With Mix
cdn('js/app.js');

// Without Mix
cdn('js/app.js', false);
```

I've stripped down your function a bit because:

- `env('CDN_URI')` has the same effect as `env('CDN_URI', '')`
- and `'/' . ltrim($file, '/')` is exactly the same as just having `$file` when using `mix()`.

Comment: thanks Bogdan!  Unfortunately, I tried this and it won't work for me because I'm accessing the JS file through a custom CDN helper like this: `<script src="{{ cdn('/js/app.js') }}"></script>`

Comment: And what does your `cdn()` helper function look like? Maybe there is a way to work around that limitation. Please update your question to include the relevant code for the `cdn()` function.

Comment: thanks so much Bodgan!  The cdn helper is being used throughout the whole project.  Would the modified cdn helper have any adverse effect for files that are not being used with the mix helper?

Comment: This will work as long as the files referenced using the `cdn` (and by extension the `mix` function) have been compiled using Laravel Mix. That's because when Laravel Mix compiles any files it will add them to the `public/mix-manifest.json` file, that is used to generate the version hashes (you can open that file yourself to see how it looks). **In short**, as long as you use Laravel Mix to manage your JS resources for the project, you should have absolutely no problems using the `cdn()` helper function everywhere.

Comment: If you'd like to use the `cdn()` helper with files that are not used with Laravel Mix you can just add a second parameter that conditionally uses one version or another. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: I just saw in the comment it said:

`// With Mix
cdn('js/app.js');

// Without Mix
cdn('js/app.js', false);`

Wouldn't it be the other way around since `false` is the default argument so I wouldn't have to specify it being false, only need to specify it when i want it to be true?

Comment: You can do it however is more convenient for you. I was just offering a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the mix helpers; Laravel has everything you need built in to make sure your blade templates always include your versioned link when you use mix...

Check out here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting